# Регулярное выражение для русского автомобильного номера

Tags: регулярные-выражения

помогите переделать регулярку для парсинга 9-и значного автомобильного номера (для 8-и значного нашел)

формат 8-и значного: аХХХааХХ

формат 9-и значного: аХХХааХХХ

Где а - буквы русского алфавита, Х - цифры

Для 8-и значного:

```
/^[а-яё\-\s]{1}[0-9]{3}(?<!0{3})[а-яё\-\s]{2}[0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: Замените `[0-9]{2}$` на `[0-9]{3}$` или `[0-9]{2,3}$` (если требуется поддержка обоих форматов). Это для PHP? А верно, что первые три цифры не должны быть нулями?

Comment: А еще не забудьте про номера такси и транспорта, там на 1 букву меньше и порядок чуть другой.

Comment: И не забывайте, что в номерах встречаются далеко не все буквы русского алфавита. Буквы "я", например, нет.

Comment: а если быть точным, то всего 12 букв: `АВЕКМНОРСТУХ`.

Comment: У - единственная буква, по которой можно понять, что это действительно кириллица)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В общем, с учётом вышесказанного в комментариях, регулярка для 8/9 может выглядеть так:

```
/^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{3}(?<!000)[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{2,3}$/ui
```

Ну и да, стоит уточнить, что это работает только для номеров частных транспортных средств.

Существуют также:

- транспорт/такси: `/^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{3}(?<!000)\d{2,3}$/ui`
- прицепы: `/^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{4}(?<!0000)\d{2,3}$/ui`
- мото, c/х техника: `/^\d{4}(?<!0000)[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{2,3}$/ui`
- транзит: `/^[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{3}(?<!000)[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{2,3}$/ui`
- выездные: `/^Т[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{3}(?<!000)\d{2,3}$/ui`

Ещё есть МВД, дипломаты, военные, федеральные(без региона)...

Comment: Вообще-то первые 3 цифры не могут быть `000`, но могут быть `001`, `010` и т.д.

Comment: Да, с регионами тоже всё видимо непросто) можно что-то вроде `[017]?\d{2}` влепить

Comment: а для не-автомобилей трёхциферные регионы используются?

Comment: Не уверен, но почему бы и нет? Мало ли..

Comment: А ещё, очень редко, раз-два в год, но на дорогах все же встречаются машины с номерами советского формата: XX-XX aaa и aXXXXaa.

Answer (score 5):

Делал себе для определения соответствия российским ГРЗ.

```
/(([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{1,2})(\d{2,3})|(\d{4}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2})(\d{2})|(\d{3}C?D{1,2}\d{3})(\d{2})|([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]{2}\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{2})|([АВЕКМНОРСТУХ]\d{4})(\d{2})|(\d{3}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{2})|(\d{4}[АВЕКМНОРСТУХ])(\d{2}))/i
```

Comment: UPD: https://regex101.com/r/q1lACR/2

Answer (score 1):

А еще можно вместо проверки госномера на соответствие формату попробовать автоматически исправлять ошибки ручного ввода госномера пользователем.

Я написал на python библиотечку [`gosnomer`](https://pypi.org/project/gosnomer/) - попробуйте, может, это именно то, что нужно вашему проекту?

Comment: Данный вопрос о регулярных выражениях. Как относится к нему или отвечает на него ваше сообщение?

Comment: А мне показалось, что вопрос не только о регулярных выражениях, но еще и о решении прикладной задачи, касающейся правильности подаваемых пользователем автомобильных номеров.

Comment: _Регулярное выражение для русского автомобильного номера_ - всё после "для" автор мог спокойно опустить, т.к. требуемый формат приведён в вопросе, а для чего он нужен особой роли не играет.